# WEKA: Converting csv file to arff file

Tags: weka

I am trying to convert csv file to arff file using ArffViewer (Tools -> ArffViewer -> File -> Save as...) With this the arff file is created but without any contents (empty file). My question is:

1. Why is it creating an empty file and how to fix it.

sample of csv file:
(All attribute types are nominal)

[image]

Comment: how does your csv file look (what data, quotes, fields, does it have a header?)?

Comment: @Markus1189 : I have uploaded the sample csv file having the 1st row as a header